# 'new' keyword in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

How come in dart in a line of code such as this one:

```
MaterialPageRouter(builder: (context) => MyWidget())
```

We are returning MyWidget class with out instantiating it with the keyword new as in `new MyWidget()` ? Are we just returning the class itself and something happens under the hood that uses the `new keyword` to do whats required. Or something else is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new` became optional in Dart 2. You can just omit it or write it. It doesn't make a difference.

`MyWidget()` creates a new instances and this is what is returned.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense now. Thanks